# Changing the default fallback substitution fonts in Linux ubuntu cyrillic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, fonts, vimrc

In VIM need correct view cyrillic font. But NERD fonts, not support cyrillic. How to set default cyrillic font in system?

P.S: ubuntu 17.04, 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the font preference in `fontconfig`-complying programs by editing `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`.

Comment: in ~/.config/ not exist folder fontconfig